# Can I start a new conversation with the same number or Apple ID in Messages?

Tags: ios, messages

Sometimes my conversations get long and unwieldy over time, but being so sentimental I'd like to keep them around on my devices (and not just leave them in iTunes backups that I might not be able to access again later).

In the Messages app, can I start a new conversation with a person under the same number or Apple ID, while preserving our previous conversation on my iOS device? Or if not, is there a feasible workaround (somehow involving switching numbers in the person's contact card or something)?

Comment: Not interested in a solution that works on the Mac at this time, but if anyone can come up with something that's guaranteed to continue working when OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion is released, bonus points to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to start a new conversation, or thread, is if the recipient has a different email address. For example, multiple emails can be stored under one contact, but messages sent to and from different emails are stored in a new thread.

Comment: "messages sent to and from different emails are stored in a new thread" Hmmm, so if I sent somebody a message from one email, and later send the same person at the same email/number but from a different email, does that start a new thread?

Comment: No, it only applies if they reply from a different email address, or if you send a message to a new email address, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you send a new message and it has the same receiver, the messages app automatically groups that with any old messages. The threads are really designed to be conversations between people and not separate threads with new conversation topics like email